# Sum the number properties grouped by name

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, merge, soql

```
This is my function where i am merging the data:

getStaffCount(data) {
    if (data == null || data.results === null )
        return [];
    else
        return data.results.StaffCount.map(m => ({ Name: m.Name, Accounts: m.Accounts  })).
                    concat(data.results.RepProviderAccount.map(m => ({ Name: m.Name, Accnt: m.Accnt  }))).
                    concat( data.results.ProviderAccount.map(m => ({ Name: m.Name, Account: m.Account })));
}
```

This is my table

```
<PowerTable Data={{ rows: this.getStaffCount(this.props.GridData) }}  rowsPerPage={5} orderBy="Name" order="asc" >
                    <PowerColumn id='Name' columnName='Name' numeric={false} disablePadding={false} label='Profile Name' width={100}>
                    </PowerColumn>
                    <PowerColumn id='Accounts' columnName='Accounts' numeric={false} disablePadding={false} label='Staff Accounts' width={100}>
                    </PowerColumn>
                    <PowerColumn id='Account' columnName='Account' numeric={false} disablePadding={false} label='Provider Account' width={100} >
                    </PowerColumn>
                    <PowerColumn id='Accnt' columnName='Accnt' numeric={false} disablePadding={false} label='Rep Provider Account' width={100} >
                    </PowerColumn>
</PowerTable>
```

[image: This is the output currently i am getting.]

I want to add the column values if they have same profile name.(I am getting data from the SoQL queries via the Api)
This is my Data:
[image]

This is the function where i am grouping and uniquify them but this doesn't seem to work:

```
groupBy(column, data) {
    var groups = {};

    data.forEach(function (itm) {
      groups[itm[column]] = groups[itm[column]] || [];
      groups[itm[column]].push(itm);
    });

    return groups;
  }

   uniquify(groups) {
    var unique = [];
    for (var key in groups) {
      if (groups.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        unique.push(groups[key][0]);
      }
    }

    return unique;
  }
   arrUnique(arr) {
    var groupsByName = this.groupBy("Name", arr);
    var uniqueNames = this.uniquify(groupsByName);
   return uniqueNames;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work best with a reduce.

```js
const results = data.reduce((arr, dat) => {
  // Find the index of the item with this name...
  let index = arr.findIndex(item => item.name === dat.name)

  // If it's not -1 this will be the index where this item has
  // already been added. Otherwise it doesn't exist yet
  // so push it...
  if(index !== -1) arr[index].account += dat.account
  else arr.push(dat)
 }, [])
```

Something like that should give you an array of objects where all the `account` properties have been multiplied together.

*Note* I noticed you sometimes have 'Account' and sometimes 'Accnt' you'll have to write some extra code to make up for that. So this is just a general outline.